# What kind of singularity is possessed by $z^{-1/2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I'm learning about singularities [Stein Sharkarchi Chapter 3], and this question popped up in my mind: What kind of singularity is $f(z):= z^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ at $0$?

It doesn't seem to fall into either of these three categories:

- **Removable singularity:** It's clearly not a removable singularity as $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} |f(z)| \rightarrow \infty$
- **Essential singularity:** By Casorati-Weierstrass it's not essential singularity either since the image of the unit disc minus the origin is very clearly not dense (it completely misses a ball of radious $.9999$ centered at the origin)
- **Pole**: It's not a pole either since it contradicts this theorem because $z^nf(z)$ vanishes at $0$ for all positive integer $n$:

> If $f$ has a pole at $0$ then for a neighbourhood of $0$ there's a positive unique  integer $n$ such that $f(z) = h(z) z^{-n}$ and $h(z)$ is holomorphic and nonvanishing in the neighbourhood

So what's this singularity ? This is perplexing me.

I feel this may have something to do with the nonuniqueness of $f(z)$ around $0$ but then I know nothing about branch cuts to add substance to my intuition.

Answer (score 7):

The Casorati–Weierstrass theorem applies only when the function is holomorphic in a punctured disk around the singularity, which isn't the case here -- you need at least one branch cut where you switch to the other branch of the square root.

This is a **branch point**.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: It is possible that my understanding of the terminology is idiosyncratic. I think I got it from Stewart and Tall, _Complex Analysis_ (Cambridge University Press), which speaks about "isolated essential singularities", from which I deduced that there must be essential singularities that are not isolated.

Comment: Finally the stuff about an essential singularity is outta here.  And good riddance!

Answer (score 5):

For most purposes, such a "singularity" does not fall into the "removable, pole, or essential" classification, because it cannot be defined as a holomorphic function on any punctured neighborhood of $0$.

A classical way to think about this is that $\sqrt{z}$ *does* admit analytic continuation along every path that does not go through $0$, ... but the *monodromy* is non-trivial, so there's no single "global" holomorphic function...

Essentially equivalently, and incorporating somewhat more modern things (covering spaces, from early 20th centurey?!?! :) we could say that there simply is no globally defined $\sqrt{z}$ (with or without $-1$) on a punctured neighborhood of $0$, but there *is* one on a two-fold (ramified) cover... that "unwinds" the square root...

Also, by the way, the notion of "branch cut" is not an intrinsic thing. It's just a way of reducing the "multi-connectedness" of a set so that the monodromy group homomorphism restricted to $\pi_1$ of the cut-up region is trivial, so that there does exist a globally defined holomorphic function *off* the "cuts", and so on.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean we can reverse engineer to get if $f$ is defined on the the punctured unit disc (minus the origin) and  $|f(z)| = O(\frac{1}{|z|^{.5}})$ as $z \rightarrow 0$ then $f$ cannot be holomorphic in the unit disc minus the origin?

Comment: @Lelouch, if f is defined on the punctured unit disk and is bounded as you indicate, then it actually has a removable singularity. :)

Comment: I mean $f(z) = \Theta(\frac{1}{|z|^.5})$ (not $O(\frac{1}{|z|^.5})$), sorry (which is not bounded near $0$)

Comment: Ah, if the bound is "sharp"-ish, then there _is_ no such function holomorphic on the punctured disk, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Standard definitions: $f$ has an *isolated singularity* at $a$ if $f$ is holomorphic in $\{z:0<|z-a|<r\}$ for some $r>0$. An isolated singularity is *removable* if  ..., it is a *pole* if ..., otherwise it is an *essential singularity*.

So your function does not have an essential singularity at $0$, simply because it does not have an isolated singularity there.

Comment: So if it's not isolated singularity, then what is that singularity ? Also does that mean we can reverse engineer to get if $f$ is defined on the the punctured unit disc (minus the origin) and  $|f(z)| = O(\frac{1}{|z|^{.5}})$ as $z \rightarrow 0$ then $f$ cannot be holomorphic in the unit disc minus the origin ?

Comment: @David the essential singularity stuff is gone and good riddance.  Please remove the last paragraph to avoid any confusion.  Thanks.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks for the update. It went away while I slept - probably would have noticed eventually, maybe.

Comment: @Lelouch I don't quite understand your question. The function $f(z)=0$ is holomorphic in the unit disk and is $O(1/|z|^{1/2})$. TThe function in your question has a _branch point_ at $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oops sorry, I mean $\Theta(\frac{1}{|z|^.5})$

Comment: There is no holomorphic function in the punctured disk with that growth; it's an easy exercise to show that $f=o(1/|z|)$ implies the singularity is removable.